# Yb50qt-5 choking out

Tags: scooter, stall

2015 Yiban Delray cuts out when giving more than 1/8 throttle. I changed the plug and fuel filter and gas cap, but it still does it. I can get to about 7 mph before it dies out. Sometimes, it runs  with no problems for 10 minutes, then I'm walking it home. It is fuel injected and sometimes it smells of gas, so I'm guessing it is running rich. [image][image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is a Yiban? I did a cursory search on Google and it popped nothing which would work for this SE ... ? I'm assuming it's either a motorcycle or a scooter?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 based on the model number, I would assume a generic 139QMB-based scooter

Comment: Make sure you have good fuel and there is no water in the tank.

Comment: Yiben/propel delray yb50qt-5. It idles with no problem think it could be fuel related to the top end. I just drained the tank and put freash gas and its still doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The old owner told me that he left it outside for a month in the rain. Water got in the carb and added dry gas and let it run for 3 hours at idle and it runs fine now. Just got back a day ago from out of state family emergency things are good there now too